# Using Jsch to run confirmable commands in CLI

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

Is there any way to use Jsch to execute command that requires the confirmation, like the following one:

```
>reboot
Please confirm (y/n)? y
```

Didn't find any answer on this or the documentation on how to do it. Tried to execute "reboot", then read the output till "(y/n)?" is faced and then printing "y" into the stream.
Though, no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing to the OutputStream you get with [getOutputStream()](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html#getOutputStream%28%29) on the [ChannelExec](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelExec.html) after reading the InputStream and waiting for the phrase 'Please confirm...'?